# How can I install bluetooth driver in lenovo B570e?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, lenovo

Any body help me out to install bluetooth driver in lenovo B570e.

Comment: please tell your harware with pasting result of lsusb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo service network-manager stop
sudo rmmod acer_wmi
sudo modprobe acer_wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo service network-manager start
sudo rmmod -f acer_wmi

then to get the settings to stick after reboot type

sudo su
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit

and you will have working wifi and also bluetooth
for further detail visit the site http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201206-11154/